# Is my proof right?(Galois extension)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Q) $E$ is a Galois extension of the $F$

Let $G=Aut(E/F)$ and $S_\alpha = \{g \in G \vert g(\alpha)=\alpha \}$ for $ \alpha \in E$

Say the $i : E \to E$ is a identity mapping

Prove "If $S_\alpha = \langle i \rangle$, then  $ E=F(\alpha)$"

---

I solved this question by myself. But there is not any solution in my workbook. So I can't check my proof is right or not. Here is my attempt.

$pf)$ Since the $E$ is a Galois extension, $G(E/F)$ is a Galois group which means $G(=Aut(E/F)) = G(E/F)$

By the Galois correspondence, only have to show $S_\alpha = G(E/F(\alpha))$. Because it is equal to $[E;F(\alpha)] =1$

First it is clear $i \in G(E/F(\alpha))$, so $\langle i \rangle \subset G(E/F(\alpha))$

Therefore  $S_\alpha(=\langle i \rangle) \subset G(E/F(\alpha))$

On the other hand, Let the $\forall h \in G(E/F(\alpha))$
Then $h \in S_\alpha$ because it fixes $F(\alpha) $ and $h \in Aut(E)$.

So $G(E/F(\alpha)) \subset S_\alpha$

Any comments or advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this a bit quicker using the subfield of $E$ fixed by a subgroup of $G$:

- $E^{\langle i \rangle} = E$
- $E^{S_\alpha} = F(\alpha)$

therefore if $\langle i \rangle = S_\alpha$ then $E = F(\alpha)$.

Comment: thanks for suggest more effective way! :) But I wanted to figure out my method is right or not.